# I have data in Excel like below, i want to display two things here

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have data in Excel like below, i want to display two things here.

1 ) If urea  column H = - then column B should change color.

2) If MR +, VP should  automatically come as -

```
SLNo     SID      RV       TT       BSA      XLD      Lact.    Urea     TSI      Ind.     MR       VP       Cit.     Nitrate  Oxid     ONPG     PCR      SALM?    
                           S        B        H2S      G        R                                                                                                  
1        R.13     +        K        A        -        -        +        -        +        -        +        -        -                 -                          
2        5 TB     -        K        K        -        -        +        -        +        -        +        -        -                                            
3        7.3R     +        K        A        -        -        +        -        +        -        +        -        -                 +                          
4        11.1R    +        K        A        +        -        +        -        +        -        +        -        -                                            
5        15       +        K        A        -        -        +        -        +        -        +        -        -                                            
6        16.2RB   -        K                 +        -        +        -        +        -        D        -        -                                            
7        18.04    -        K        K        -        -        +        -        +        -        +        -        -                 -                          
8        18.1R             K        K        -        -        +        -        -        -        +        +        -                 -                          
9        20.2R             K        A        -        -        +        -        +        -        +        -        -                 +                          
10       20.3T    -        K        A        -        -        +        -        +        -        +        -        -                 +                          
11       R3D/ 28.1-        K                 +        -        +        -        +        -        -        --       -        +        +
```

## ans 1 :

I have used Conditional formatting option and =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H5, "-")), this works, but problem is Blank in Urea column also Highlighting the color

## ans 2 : Pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

**Ans 1:**  Your CF formula is incorrect. Find_Text is the first argument; within_text is the second Try:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",H2))
```

or, simpler

```
=H2 = "-"
```

**Ans 2**:  You could use an event-triggered macro.  To enter this event-triggered Macro, right click on the sheet tab.
Select "View Code" from the right-click drop-down menu.
Then paste the code below into the window that opens.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rMR As Range, rVP As Range
    Dim C As Range
With Cells
    Set rMR = .Find(what:="MR", after:=[a1], LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    Set rVP = .Find(what:="VP")
End With
    If Not rMR Is Nothing And Not rVP Is Nothing Then
        Set rMR = Range(rMR, Cells(Rows.Count, rMR.Column).End(xlUp))
        Set rVP = rVP.Resize(rowsize:=rMR.Rows.Count)
```

Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, rMR) Is Nothing Then
        For Each C In Intersect(Target, rMR)
            If C.Value = "+" Then rVP(C.Row).Value = "-"
        Next C
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, rVP) Is Nothing Then
        For Each C In Intersect(Target, rVP)
            If rMR(C.Row).Value = "+" Then C.Value = "-"
        Next C
    End If
   End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub